# In the Elastic stack, how can we automatically generate and apply an enrollment token for kibana through docker-compose?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I'm trying to setup a full Elastic stack using docker-compose. Getting the "ELK" components working wasn't too bad. Now I want to add Fleet and APM into the mix, but this has led to several new problems, mostly around the security configuration.

I have been able to figure out how to automatically generate and apply security certificates and keys through the use of a shared volume. However, creating the enrollment token for kibana really has me stumped.

Things I've tried:

#### Use the API to generate the token from an init container

This doesn't work because there doesn't seem to be an endpoint for this behavior. I did find
[this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/security-api-kibana-enrollment.html#security-api-kibana-enrollment-desc) but it clearly says it is for internal use only and should not be used.

I also found
[this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/71438) to create such an API, and although it was merged and completed, trying to hit that endpoint results in an error. I cannot find any documentation on it at all other than this one closed issue, so I don't know if it was removed later or what happened, but it doesn't seem to be an option.

Also looked at [service accounts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/service-accounts.html#authenticate-with-service-account-token), but it doesn't seem like these can be used in place of enrollment.

#### Use another elastic container to run the enrollment token generator

This also did not work because `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token` can only be run from within the real configured elasticsearch node. Trying to run it in the init container results in an error about not being able to determine the health of the cluster. Also, according to
[this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/43999) the cluster must be fully
initialized and running before the command will work, which means I can't run it in a `command:`
block because it will prevent the container from starting successfully with the healthcheck, in a sort of chicken and egg problem.

#### Install sshd inside elasticsearch

Now that I know the container must be fully running first, and the command must be run from inside the container after that, my last option was to try and install sshd and use the init server to run the command through ssh. I attempted to create a new Dockerfile using the elasticsearch image as a base, and then install and configure sshd, and finally recreating the original entrypoint. This also ended in failure because the elasticsearch image uses an init system called tini, and adding a command to start sshd before running the container didn't work with the init because it no longer had the first PID, which is required.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this beyond the basic "ELK" setup, and it seems wildly complex for what it is. All of the guidance on the topic requires manual steps, but this really slows down local development when you're destroying/recreating containers constantly.

Tracking my work in [this repo](https://github.com/hexsorcerer/example-elastic-stack-aspnetcore), it currently starts and gets kibana to the point of asking for an enrollment token until the health check times out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!